# Getting a TypeError when importing BERTopic

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm using BERTopic for a project and since yesterday I can't run the import statment.

I am using Colab and following the standard procedure, that is run pip for BERTopic and then restart the session.
Here is the screenshot of the error I get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what should be the problem in this link (https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/6301).
What worked for me was importing Dask in the following format:

> %pip install "dask[complete]"